# One digit by 2 digit multiplication

Tags: arithmetic

When multiplying $$2 \times 808 
$$
we stack 1 above 0 when  multiplying $2 \times8 = 16$ then $2 \times  0 = 0+(1$ stacked)

Explain it why you just add the number $1$?

Comment: This does not make sense. Are you asking how the elementary school multiplication algorithm works?

Comment: Yes @JohnDouma I believe he’s asking specifically about the carryover method.

Comment: I’m just asking the reason why you  need to add the the 1 stacked above 0

Comment: @JohnDouma Seems so. In fact , I remember to have read that questions at any level can be on-topic, but this one is extremely basic indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let us introduce the distributive property: $$a\times(b+c)=(a\times b)+(a\times c)$$
For example, $$3\times 8=3 \times(6+2)=(3 \times6)+(3 \times2)=18+6=24$$$$45 \times22= 45\times(20+2)=(45 \times20)+(45 \times2)=900+90=990$$

Now, we realise that $808$ can be written as $$808=800+0+8$$$$=(8 \times100)+(0 \times10)+ (8\times1)$$ Now,

$$2 \times808=2 \times\Bigg [(8 \times100)+(0 \times10)+ (8\times1)\Bigg]$$$$=(2 \times8 \times100)+(2\times0 \times10)+(2 \times8 \times1)$$$$=(16 \times100)+(0 \times10)+\color{red}{(16 \times1)}$$$$=(16 \times100)+(0 \times10)+\color{red}{{(1\times 10)+(6 \times1)}}$$$$=(16 \times100)+((0\color{blue} {+1})\times10)+(6 \times1)$$

Answer (score 2):

The multiple-digit multiplication algorithm you learn in school is something that is rarely actually explained. Presumably teachers believe that 10-year-old's (or whenever it is that it is first taught) wouldn't understand it, and then it's never revisited in later years. It is just rote memorized, and the result is that most people never learn "why you just add the number 1".

To explain this, I am going to assume that you're familiar with the standard multiple-digit addition algorithm. I will also assume that multiplication means repeated addition (which isn't always the best way to think about it, but it works here).

We want $2\times808$. As multiplication is repeated addition, this turns out to be $808+808$. We will do this addition in a little roundabout way: we are going to first split everything up into hundreds, tens and ones, then add the ones together, add the tens together, add the hundreds together, and finally add together those three results.

Splitting up gives us $800+00+8+800+00+8$. Grouping by size gives us $800+800+00+00+8+8$. Now we add together the ones. But note that we have two equal terms that are added together. That's multiplication: $$8+8=2\times8=\boxed{16}.$$ Now we add the tens the same way: $$00+00=2\times00=\boxed{00}.$$Finally, the hundreds:$$800+800=2\times800=\boxed{1600}.$$

Now we add these three together:
$$
\begin{array}{cr}
&16\\
&00\\
+&1600\\\hline
=&1616\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
This is what the standard multiplication algorithm ultimately does, except it cuts away the boilerplate and lets you get straight to single-digit multiplying, and then adding up all the results in one line instead of stacked on top of one another the way I did here. The $1$ you "just add" is the $1$ from $16$ here. Note that if the tens' place had been a little more interesting, then the $1$ from $16$ would've had to be added in with whatever result we got from the tens' place.

---

A bit more compactly, again with multiplication as repeated addition:
$$\begin{array}{cr}
&\small1\phantom8\\
&808\\
+&808\\\hline
=&1616\\\hline
\end{array}$$
We get a carry when we try to add together the rightmost $8$s. What do we do with that carry? We "just add" it to whatever the result from the tens' place is. That's basically all there is to it.